# Null all Applicable Rows when a Condition is met in Single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a query for a list of Kit items with one or more component IDs for each Kit. I am wanting to Null out the Component Total Price if any of the components are inactive.

Here is a snippet of my query:

```
SELECT

BOMID,
KitID,
KitSalesPrice,
ComponentID 'CompID',
ComponentQty 'CompQty',
ComponentSalesPrice 'CompPrice',
ComponentLifecycle 'CompLifecycle',
CASE
    WHEN ComponentLifecycle = ('Active')
    THEN (SUM(ComponentSalesPrice * ComponentQty) OVER (PARTITION BY BOMID, KitID))
    ELSE NULL
END AS [CompTotalPrice],

FROM KitTable
```

This is the output that creates:

| BOMID | KitID | KitSalesPrice | CompID | CompQty | CompPrice | CompLifecycle | CompTotalPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 00-001 | $30 | 00-123 | 2 | $5 | Active | $18 |
| 001 | 00-001 | $30 | 00-111 | 1 | $3 | Active | $18 |
| 001 | 00-001 | $30 | 00-222 | 1 | $4 | Inactive | NULL |
| 001 | 00-001 | $30 | 00-333 | 1 | $1 | Active | $18 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 002 | 00-002 | $50 | 00-444 | 3 | $3 | Active | $22 |
| 002 | 00-002 | $50 | 00-555 | 2 | $4 | Active | $22 |
| 002 | 00-002 | $50 | 00-666 | 5 | $1 | Active | $22 |

and what I would like the output to be is:

| BOMID | KitID | KitPrice | CompID | CompQty | CompPrice | CompLifecycle | CompTotalPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 00-001 | $30 | 00-123 | 2 | $5 | Active | NULL |
| 001 | 00-001 | $30 | 00-111 | 1 | $3 | Active | NULL |
| 001 | 00-001 | $30 | 00-222 | 1 | $4 | Inactive | NULL |
| 001 | 00-001 | $30 | 00-333 | 1 | $1 | Active | NULL |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 002 | 00-002 | $50 | 00-444 | 3 | $3 | Active | $22 |
| 002 | 00-002 | $50 | 00-555 | 2 | $4 | Active | $22 |
| 002 | 00-002 | $50 | 00-666 | 5 | $1 | Active | $22 |

Is this  possible?

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

Comment: Just use a windowed `COUNT` to check if there are any `NULL` values in the partition.=, instead of just checking the *row's* value.

Comment: You also need to show your sample starting data.

Answer (score 0):

Your data

```
CREATE TABLE KitTable(
   BOMID         INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,KitID         VARCHAR(100)
  ,KitSalesPrice VARCHAR(100)
  ,ComponentID        VARCHAR(100)
  ,ComponentQty       INTEGER 
  ,ComponentSalesPrice     VARCHAR(100)
  ,ComponentLifecycle VARCHAR(100)
);
INSERT INTO KitTable
(BOMID,KitID,KitSalesPrice,ComponentID,ComponentQty,ComponentSalesPrice,ComponentLifecycle) VALUES
(1,'00-001','$30','00-123',2,'$5','Active'),
(1,'00-001','$30','00-111',1,'$3','Active'),
(1,'00-001','$30','00-222',1,'$4','Inactive'),
(1,'00-001','$30','00-333',1,'$1','Active'),
(2,'00-002','$50','00-444',3,'$3','Active'),
(2,'00-002','$50','00-555',2,'$4','Active'),
(2,'00-002','$50','00-666',5,'$1','Active');
```

you should use `min over partition by`, Isnull and IFF in your query to get your desired result

```
SELECT
BOMID,
KitID,
KitSalesPrice,
ComponentID 'CompID',
ComponentQty 'CompQty',
ComponentSalesPrice 'CompPrice',
ComponentLifecycle 'CompLifecycle',
----IIF(ComponentLifecycle = ('Active'),1,0),  
--MIN(IIF(ComponentLifecycle = ('Active'),1,0))  OVER (PARTITION BY BOMID, KitID ) ,
isnull(MIN(IIF(ComponentLifecycle = ('Active'),1,0))  OVER (PARTITION BY BOMID, KitID ) *(CASE
    WHEN ComponentLifecycle = ('Active')
    THEN (SUM(RIGHT(ComponentSalesPrice,1) * ComponentQty) OVER (PARTITION BY BOMID, KitID))
    ELSE NULL END ) ,0)
 AS [CompTotalPrice]
FROM KitTable
```

however, I recommend using it in subquery to not be confused.

```
select 
BOMID,
KitID,
KitSalesPrice,
CompID,
CompQty,
CompPrice,
CompLifecycle,
Isnull(p*CompTotalPrice,0) [CompTotalPrice]
from (
SELECT
BOMID,
KitID,
KitSalesPrice,
ComponentID 'CompID',
ComponentQty 'CompQty',
ComponentSalesPrice 'CompPrice',
ComponentLifecycle 'CompLifecycle',
MIN(IIF(ComponentLifecycle = ('Active'),1,0))  OVER (PARTITION BY BOMID, KitID ) AS p,
CASE
    WHEN ComponentLifecycle = ('Active')
    THEN (SUM(RIGHT(ComponentSalesPrice,1) * ComponentQty) OVER (PARTITION BY BOMID, KitID))
    ELSE NULL
END AS [CompTotalPrice]
FROM KitTable) k
```

[Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3iQLbfRa)